# JButton added to JPanel doesn't show

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to add a JButton to a JPanel.
I have a PropWindow (JFrame) that has a PropView (JPanel) in it. the PropView-JPanel seems to be added correctly because I can draw shapes on it with paint().
But when I use this to try adding a button it just won't show up att all :/

```
JButton testButton;

public PropView(int width, int height) {
    super(true);

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(width, height);

    //TestButton
    testButton = new JButton("Test");
    testButton.setLocation(10,10);
    testButton.setSize(100, 50);
    testButton.setVisible(true);

    add(testButton);

    setFocusable(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The JFrame and the JPanel are both 250x600 px.

Comment: The reason for your mistake is not shown in your post. I suggest 1) that you consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Avoid using null layouts and absolute positioning like the plague as this will get you into trouble.

Comment: Have you tried adding the button to the `JFrame` instead?

Comment: Show your paint code, that may be messing it up, especially if you are using the wrong paint method.

Comment: I'm with @NESPowerGlove. If you are overriding the `paint(...)` method of a JFrame, you're doing your graphics wrong, and this can have bad effects throughout a program.

Comment: Thanks! It was that paint()-method that was messing it up. I had some code in it that I deleted but forgot to remove the method itself. When I removed the overridden paint() the button showed up fine!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the code snippet you posted but just in case: make sure you call `pack ()` on the frame **after** you have added the panel or any other components.

Also, it's usually discouraged to extend a JPanel or JFrame, unless you have a good reason to do it, just a heads up.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) you have a short tutorial about displaying frames:

And some sample code in it that might help:

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you added PropPanel to PropWindow using `myPropWindow.getContentPane().add(myPropPanel)`, not just `myPropWindow.add(myPropPanel)`.

Comment: This advice is guaranteed not to help since both calls do exactly the same thing. Please delete or improve this answer.

Comment: Really? Huh. I always had trouble with stuff not showing up until I switched to adding them to the content pane instead of to the window root, but maybe I was doing something else wrong.

Comment: Don't take my word for it -- look at the JFrame API section on the `add(...)` method. And I quote, `"As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary."`